# Create Feature Class from another Feature Class using ArcObjects for .net application in C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, feature-class, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have a `Feature Class` and I want to create another `Feature Class` that is basically a subset of the first `Feature Class`. For example, I have a `Feature Class` containing public parks which I want to use to create a new `Feature Class` containing only certain parks.

Should I be using the `IQueryFilter` interface or is there a better/easier way to do this?

I am creating a .net application in C#.

Comment: Why not simply call the Select tool through the IGeoProcessor with your SQL expression? You create a new dataset which is your subset.

Comment: I would do as @Hornbydd said, much less lines of code. Have a read of https://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1207/files/gp_arcobjects.pdf. I prefer to use the GeoProcessor and each tool as an object rather than IGeoProcessor and the tool as a string but that's just a personal preference; I'm sure in the end the results are the same. Would you like an example of both methods?

Comment: Both examples would be nice.

Comment: This site does not provide coded solutions w/o providing an example of what you've tried so far.  To learn about using the geoprocessor check out this link: http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0410/gpandnet.html

Comment: @artwork21 The intention of my question was to get advice on how to approach my problem. I never asked for a code solution in my question. When another user offered to provide examples of both methods he suggested, I accepted.